# Ubuntu isn't on Google's list of Summer of Code participants

Tags: community

Google have just published their [list of accepted mentoring organisations](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/program/accepted_orgs/google/gsoc2011) for Summer of Code 2011, but Ubuntu isn't listed there. Jono Bacon has confirmed that Ubuntu applied for a position, so I can only conclude that the application was unsuccessful. Can anyone clarify whether or not this is the case?

Comment: i don't think ubuntu needs GSoC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know Ubuntu did not get through. It is not there in the list.

Ubuntu got [through last year(2010)](http://socghop.appspot.com/gsoc/program/accepted_orgs/google/gsoc2010) where we had a few projects (one I can remember was Harvest)

In 2010 openSUSE did not get through. They got through this year.

Ubuntu did not get [through in 2009](http://socghop.appspot.com/gsoc/program/accepted_orgs/google/gsoc2009).

This all fine. Ubuntu is a pretty big project. GSoC is a initiative to boost FOSS mentality.

This time Google themselves said that [smaller organizations should also apply](http://lists.p2pu.org/pipermail/p2pu-dev/2011-February/000288.html). Looks like Google thought that Ubuntu doesn't need GSoC students.

Comment: Sounds fair enough.